# Simple APEX String Replacement - can't unencode quotation marks

Tags: apex, api, regular-expressions, pattern, replaceall

I've tried quite a few different methods to unencode a simple string but nothing's turning up.

That's the end of my API call, using a regex solution I found online, although it's not working out.

```
Http http = new Http();
HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
res = http.send(req);
String body = res.getBody();

Pattern theResponseRaw = Pattern.compile('[q]');
body = theResponseRaw.matcher(body).replaceAll('');

return body;
```

When I `console.log()` back in JavaScript on the VF page, I get:

```
{&quot;meta&quot;:{&quot;reuest&quot;:{&quot;params&quot;
```

---

I've tried `unescapeHtml3()`, `unescapeHtml4()`, `unescapeJava()`, and  `unescapeUnicode`.

I assumed this would be straightforward. Any suggestions?

---

Full Method APEX code:

```
@RemoteAction
public static String SMReturn(String url) {
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint(url);
    req.setMethod('GET');

    String AuthHeader = 'Bearer ey....';
    req.setHeader('Authorization', AuthHeader);

    Http http = new Http();
    HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
    res = http.send(req);
    String body = res.getBody().unescapeHtml4();
    return body;

   }
```

---

JS Code:

I used the commented out lines to change the returned APEX string into a string with quotes. I don't want to do this method because I'd rather have proper JSON on server side incase I ever want to parse JSON server side.

```
Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction('{!$RemoteAction.ClientPortalHomeController.SMReturn}',
    'https://api.<rest_of_url>',
    function(json,event) {
        // var res = $('<div/>').html(json).text();
        // res = JSON.parse(res);
        console.log(json);
    }
)
```

Comment: JSON returned from a reasonable web service would not be encoded so you could just feed it straight into e.g. `JSON.deserialize`. If you wrote the web service you are calling and it is outputting encoded text fix that end to not encode.

Comment: Whenever I put `res.getBody()` into `JSON.deserialize()`, I get `Illegal assignment from Object to String`. I've also tried this API call in Postman and elsewhere, it gives me a proper response which is not encoded. Something is happening after the call which is doing it.

Comment: `System.debug(res.getBody())` to check what the code is getting. If `Object o = JSON.deserialize(res.getBody());` works then there isn't an encoding problem but a problem in how you are handling the object graph returned from the method.

Comment: dis you try setting escape false on the remote method? What does it look like in the class when you debug the body unescaped in the class

Comment: My debug logs are coming in hours after they're called. I most likely have it setup quite wrong but I basically can't access debug logs in real time. Also, how do I set escape false on remote methods?

Comment: @qarthandso - Answer updated, tested and working

Answer (score 2):

Unencode the body before deserializing.

```
String t = '{&quot;meta&quot;:{&quot;reuest&quot;:{&quot;params&quot;}}';

t = t.unescapeHtml4();
system.debug(t);
```

Results in:

```
{"meta":{"reuest":{"params"}}
```

In your case it would be:

```
String unencodedBody = resp.getBody().unescapeHtml4();
```

We would need to see your page JS code to troubleshoot that. It could be that the method you are using is HTMLEncoding the response.

**Based on your updated code**

Change your remote method to this

```
Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction({!$RemoteAction.ClientPortalHomeController.SMReturn}',
                    function(json,event) {
                        // var res = $('<div/>').html(json).text();
                        // res = JSON.parse(res);
                        console.log(json);
                    }, {escape: false}
                )
}
```

You might also find this answer helpful:

[The "Escape" in visualforce javascript remoting](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/25691/the-escape-in-visualforce-javascript-remoting)

> *mattandneil*
> Yep. It is handling XML escape characters (& " < >), not JavaScript.
> But really, most non-trival applications will use escape: false and a
> client-side template system to do any escaping.
>
> The default escape: true value is just a safety net to prevent XML
> code being dumped into the page inadvertently, for trivial
> applications which fail to escape their output.
>
> Salesforce are pushing the escaping behaviour up into the transport
> layer by default. While it's not the right place, it's in the spirit
> of preventing unaware developers from leaving themselves vulnerable to
> client-side code injection (eg).
>
> It's completely reasonable to have XML characters in the data (eg
> Grand Hotels & Resorts Ltd), and very standard front-end development
> practise to escape those XML characters before dumping output onto the
> page. Just not on the transport!
>
> Obviously the Salesforce default behaviour will cause side effects if
> one intends to send XML tags around, eg via Rich Long Text fields, or
> any crazy server-side templating happening in a controller.

Comment: I've added more to the post with the full APEX code and full JS code. I'm still getting escaped data with my updated code shown above.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that has a similar problem in the future, I figured out the solution which for me was obscured in the docs.

```
Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction('{!$RemoteAction.ClientPortalHomeController.SMReturn}',
    'https://api.....',
    function(json,event) {
        // var res = $('<div/>').html(json).text();
        // res = JSON.parse(res);
        console.log(json);
    },

    // ************** THIS IS NEEDED BELOW
    {escape: false}
)
```

`{escape: false}` disables the automatic escaping. I find it very un-needed for the default to be `false` as any non-trivial project will need to use this at some point.